# Unable to pass argument from gradle command line to Spring project (not Boot)

Tags: spring, gradle, command-line, arguments, parameter-passing

I am developing Spring project. 
I would like to load credentials from the command line not storying them in the code. I'm trying to execute this gradle command

```
gradlew build -Dspring.datasource.username=tester
```

and when I startup the Spring project, the program stops on a breakpoint and I see whether variable is declared or not. I have tried using -P instead of -D but it still didn't help.

I deploy the spring app remotely using bmuschko plugin I've tried to use, but also without success. I checked in java code Properties by using System.getProperties() and Environment object supported by Spring.

```
gradlew cargoredeployremote -Dspring.datasource.username=tester
```

Application properties are loaded succesfully.

**IMPORTANT:**  I saw many tutorials how to make it but using Spring Boot I use just selected components from Spring.
For instance: http://nixmash.com/post/passing-arguments-to-spring-boot - this doesn't work in my case because I have no bootRun task.

Any ideas? Am I missing something in my steps?

Here is my build.gradle

```
group 'example'
version '1.0.0'


apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.cargo'
apply plugin: 'org.liquibase.gradle'

compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

mainClassName = 'api.optic.config.WebAppInitializer'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

buildscript {
    repositories{
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies{
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-cargo-plugin:2.2.3'
        classpath 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-RC3'
        classpath 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.4.1'
        classpath "org.liquibase:liquibase-gradle-plugin:1.2.4"
        classpath "mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.13"
    }
}

project.ext {
    springVersion = "4.3.6.RELEASE"
    junitVersion = "5.0.0-RC3"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    compile "org.springframework:spring-core:${springVersion}"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-context:${springVersion}"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-context-support:${springVersion}"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-beans:${springVersion}"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-web:${springVersion}"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-webmvc:${springVersion}"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-orm:${springVersion}"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-oxm:${springVersion}"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-jdbc:${springVersion}"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-test:${springVersion}"
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.38'

    compile group: 'javax.mail', name: 'javax.mail-api', version: '1.5.6'


    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.25'
    compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.2.2'

    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module', name: 'jackson-module-parameter-names', version: '2.9.0.pr2'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-jdk8', version: '2.9.0.pr2'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-jsr310', version: '2.9.0.pr2'
    compile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'

    testCompile "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}"
    testRuntime("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")
}

cargo {
    containerId = 'tomcat8x'
    port = 8080

deployable {
    context = 'example'
}

remote {
    hostname = 'host.name.com'
    username = 'tomcat'
    password = 'pass'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically were 2 issues

**1.** Name mismatch: in application.properties the name inside the ${} was different than this provided from command-line

**Solution:**

```
application.properties
spring.datasource.username=${username}
```

and in gradle command-line

```
gradle build -Pusername=tester
```

**2.** Dot issue with gradle:

Can't put

```
gradle build -Pspring.datasource.username=tester
```

even if you have in application.properties

```
spring.datasource.username=${spring.datasource.username}
```

because you get an exception:

> Execution failed for task ':processResources'.
>
> Could not copy file '.\src\main\resources\application.properties' to '.\build\resources\main\application.properties'.

**Solution:**

Instead of dots use _ sign

```
gradle build -Pspring_datasource_username=tester
```

and in Application properties

```
spring.datasource.username=${spring_datasource_username}
```